# Problems with Delphi grammar for ANTLR4

Tags: delphi, grammar, antlr4, delphi-xe

I found a [ANTLR3 Delphi Grammar](https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi/blob/master/src/main/antlr3/org/sonar/plugins/delphi/antlr/Delphi.g) for Delphi which I'm trying til convert to ANTLR4. But I have a strange problem I do not understand. I have created a repo with [ANTRL4 Delphi Grammar](https://github.com/gotthardsen/Delphi-ANTRL4-Grammar)

Most thinks seems to work, but if I have a simple unit with the following:

```
unit TestParser;

interface

procedure Dim(var dd: string; const Dim1: Integer; const Dim2: Integer); overload;

implementation

procedure Dim(var dd: string; const Dim1: Integer; const Dim2: Integer); overload;
begin
  //do something
end;

end.
```

The procDecl is invoked in the interfaceDecl when the first procedure key word is found. But as soon as var and/or const i reached it breaks the procDecl and starts a varSection/constSection instead of finishing the procDecl

I must admit that I'm fairly new to ANTLR so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, try to fix all warnings in grammar such as a `rule contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string`.

Comment: Did you try to modify and use [pascal.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/pascal/pascal.g4) grammar from an official grammars repository?

Answer (score 0):

The whole issue hinges on the variable name `dd`.

It seems that for some reason the parser mistakes this as a hex number. You get the same effect when you change the name to something like `123`.

As soon as you change the name so that it cannot be mistaken for a number (e.g. just add a character from the range g-z) everything is fine. But why this happens I cannot explain.

BTW: Thanks for Delphi.g4.

Comment: I had a similar issue when using this grammar to parse "function f: Integer". There are some assembler specific tokens that interfere with the rest of the language, which, in my case, caused f: to be recognised as TkAsmHexLabel. The lexer doesn't know better, and I don't know if there's a way to make it aware of the context in ANTLR. An alternative would be to remove all asm specific rules and replace them with a single asm rule that reads from 'asm' up to the first 'end'. Use a separate grammar to parse the retrieved asm rule's text if interested, otherwise just ignore it.

Comment: I just commented out the TkAsmHexLabel rule and was working